# Android Java equivalent of PHP implode function

Tags: android, implode

I've copied a snippet of a function I use in php to take an array and convert it into a sql where clause using the implode function. I would like to be able to repeat this function in Android Java code.

In other words pass a function a json array and have it do the equivalent of the implode function below to create the where clause in the query string. Does Java in Android have an "implode" equivalent or would anyone be able to help with an elegant solution to creating that where clause from a json array in Android Java? The json array would be of the form {"var1":"val1", "var2":"val2"}

```
   // select from fact sighings - requires an array to do the where clause
    public function select_from_fact_sighting($whereArray) {


        $jsonArray = json_decode($whereArray, true);
        $elementCount  = count($jsonArray);        

        $where = array();

        foreach($jsonArray as $row) {
            foreach($row as $key => $val) {
                $qval = $this -> quote($val);
                $where[] = $key . " = " . $qval;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($where))
            $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM fact_sightings WHERE %s', implode(' AND ', $where)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin you convert your JSON objects into string list and pass like this to get the string form of the json with appended string

```
fun main(){

    val arrayOrg = arrayOf("a","b","b","c","a","c","a")

    println(arrayOrg.joinToString(" "))
}
```

//prints

a b b c a c a

in Java I guess this should work.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    String gfg2 = String.join("  ", "select", "*", "from", "table", "where"); 

    System.out.println(gfg2); 
}
```